# How do I take summations in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to take the summation of i^2 where i = 1:25, but I can't get it right. For reference, my code is:
'''

```
my.sum <- 0
  for(i in 1:25){
    sum1 <- i^2)
    my.sum = my.sum + sum1
  }
my.sum
```

'''

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have one `)` after `i^2`, so it will work after remove that

```
my.sum <- 0
for (i in 1:25) {
  sum1 <- i^2
  my.sum <- my.sum + sum1
}

> my.sum
[1] 5525
```

---

Actually you can use the code below for short

```
> sum(seq(25)**2)
[1] 5525
```